# Transfer scrolling from List Box to Window when end of scroll is reached

Tags: javascript, events, web, scroll

I have a [List Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/listbox) on a long form that does not fit on screen.

When the end of the list box is reached while scrolling, I want the scrolling action to be passed to the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) element so users can continue scrolling down the form without clicking out of the List Box.

I have managed to capture the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) when the end of scrolling is reached on the List Box, but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: That should happen automatically. I need sample code to test.

Comment: It does but you have to stop scrolling, I'm trying to make it seamless. I think the default behavior is acceptable but I'm working with product team.